# Is it true in the Group of Symmetries that (ab)(ac) = (acb)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Suppose $1 \le a,b,c \le n$ and $a\ne b$, $a\ne c$, $b\ne c$. Is it true in $S_n$ that $(ab)(ac)=(acb)$?

I'm generally new to the subject of Applied/Abstract Algebra and feel as if this is easier than it seems and I'm just overlooking something.

I know that to break up permutation cycles of length $\gt 2$ than you would do $(abc)\Rightarrow(ab)(ac)$, so if I'm not mistaken what my question is stating is that $(abc)\Rightarrow(ac)(ab)$ is possible too, which I believe implies the group is Abelian for all $n$?

I am also aware that $S_n$ is not Abelian for $n\ge 3$, which I have found at this link: http://faculty.atu.edu/mfinan/4033/absalg6.pdf under Theorem 6.3

So, would the answer to my question be "no it is not true for $n\ge 3$"?

Comment: Why would it imply the group is abelian ?

Comment: @CaptainLama It's just an assumption. Since if commutativity held then (ac)(ab) = (ab)(ac) = (acb).. right?

Comment: Actually $(acb)\neq (abc)$. The first sends $a$ to $c$ and the other to $b$, so they are not the same permutations.

Comment: So to answer my question, $(ab)(ac)\ne (acb)$ because $(ab)(ac) = (abc)$ and $(abc) \ne (acb)$? @CaptainLama

Comment: No, you do have $(ab)(ac) = (acb)$ but it doesn't imply that the group is abelian, so no contradiction anywhere.

Comment: I see, so what would be the appropriate approach to proving this? @CaptainLama

Comment: Just try to see that $(ab)(ac)$ has the same action as $(acb)$ on $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I think I got it, $(acb)$ can be transposed as $(cb)(ab)=(abc)=(ab)(ac)$ @CaptainLama